# Brute Force method for twoSum problem doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, brute-force

Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target.
ex :

```
Input: nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9  
Output: [0,1]  
Output: Because nums[0] + nums[1] == 9, we return [0, 1]
```

and,my code doesnt' work on test case:
[2,5,5,11]
output
[1,1]

Which should be [1,2], but it returns [1,1], i can't grasp the wrong line in here.
and, here's my code

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        a=[0,0]
        for i in range(len(nums)-1):
            for j in range(1, len(nums)):
                if((nums[i]+nums[j])==target):
                     return i,j
        return none 
#test case
#[2,5,5,11]
#10
#Output
#[1,1]
```

Comment: Simply check that i and j differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    nums =[2,5,5,11]
    target = 10
    for i in range(len(nums)-1):
        for j in range(i+1, len(nums)):
            if((nums[i]+nums[j])==target):
                 print(i,j)
```